# Is there a way for a bard to use bardic music without sonic components?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, stealth, bard

I am trying to figure out is if there is anyway for a bard to use his bardic music abilities (Inspire courage, inspire greatness and the like) **without** My party or the enemy needing to hear me.

Comment: Also worth noting that nothing can do anything about the verbal comp0nents of bardic spellcasting: the rules actually say every bard spell has one, and Still Spell *et al.* cannot change that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bardic Music with visual or silent performance types](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/36935/bardic-music-with-visual-or-silent-performance-types)

Comment: Are you just trying to conceal your bardic performance, or are you trying to affect people who *cannot* hear you (e.g. you're inside a Silence spell, desired target is deafened, etc.)?

Answer (score 3):

**No.**

---

From the [SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/bard.htm)

> **Bardic Music**
>   While these abilities fall under the category of bardic music and the descriptions discuss singing or playing instruments, **they can all be activated by reciting poetry, chanting, singing lyrical songs, singing melodies, whistling, playing an instrument, or playing an instrument in combination with some spoken performance**.

Emphasis mine. 
It's no specified any other kind of Perform, and all of the mentioned above have a sound component as a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

SUBSONICS
Your music can affect even those who do not consciously
hear it.
Prerequisite: Perform (any) 10 ranks, bardic music.
Benefit: You can produce music or poetics so subtly
that opponents do not notice it, yet your allies still gain
all the usual benefits from your bardic music. Similarly,
you can affect opponents within range with your music,
but unless they can see you performing or have some
other means of discovering it, they cannot determine
the source of the effect.

Page 112 out of Complete Adventurer

Comment: This still requires them to be able to hear it — they just don't *consciously* hear it or notice it.

Comment: What situation are you trying to gain benefit for? Are you trying to get a deaf person to gain the benefit for your bardic music? Or are you just trying to hide that you are using it so that you do not have a target on your head?

Comment: And if you want to get down to the RAW of the ruling on the feat, completely  ignoring the spirit of it, you could then say that Deaf people could then be effected by the Bardic Music, as they do not consciously hear it. It has no mechanic or rulings for people who unconsciously hear it, the RAW of the rule is for those who **cannot** consciously hear it.

Comment: As *literally* written the question is about affecting people without them “needing to hear”, but now that you mention it, I agree it's not super-clear if that distinction is intended by the question, or why. I'm not the asker of the question, so I can't clarify those for you, but since you won't be able to comment on others' posts before earning 50 rep, [I have passed on the question to the asker of the question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/94687/is-there-a-way-for-a-bard-to-use-bardic-music-without-sonic-components/95102?noredirect=1#comment220266_94687) for you. Cheers!